# OnTriggerExit event missing when object become disable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am stopping tram animation as it hit with the car collider using **OnTriggerEnter** and starting tram animation again on **TriggerExit**. It is working fine but the problem is OnTriggerExit event is **missing/skipping** when my car object become disable. Like

- Tram hit the car and stop (OnTriggerEnter executed)
- Car Object become disable (OnTriggerExit missed)

Now, you will ask why car object become disable? The answer is car object are spawning around the camera and if i move my camera to a certain place it will spawn car object at that position and it will delete the cars from previous location (Remember car spawning system is third party system and i cannot change it, it is dll).

Comment: OnTriggerExit wouldn't work anyway, as the object is disabled. So, you should find an alternative.
Shouldn't the tram be able to move when the car is disabled? You can set a small delay when the car get's disabled and then start the tram.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for confirmation. I have posted this question so that someone provide me the alternative.

Comment: Actually Car disable spawning and disable mecahnism is not in my hand as i have told in the question.

Comment: In that case, you can add a custom script in the car prefab and in it's OnDisable function send message to your trum.

Comment: Yes, This can be a solution let me try it. if it will work i will tell you. Then you should answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the car is disabled, you won't get the OnTriggerExit event

What you can do is:

- If you have enough control on the car object (even tough you use a dll): put the car in a child object. The car parent has the collider and isn't disabled. Only the child object with the car visual becomes disabled. Then you will be able to get the event
- If this first solution doesn't suit you, you can also add a script to the car that triggers an event when OnDisable is called. This might be more complicated if you can disable the car under other circumstances when you don't want the event to be triggered